# Repair sentences that have line breaks in the middle of them: Python is \n is fun

Tags: python, regex, nltk

I am currently extracting text from PDFs using Apache Tika. I am using NLTK to do named entity recognition and other tasks. I am encountering an issue where sentences in the pdf document are extracted with line breaks in the middle of them. For example,

> I am a sentence that has a python line \nbreak in the middle of it.

The pattern is usually a space followed by a line break, `<space>\n` or sometimes `<space>\n<space>`. I want to repair these sentences so I can use a sentence tokenizer on them.

I am trying to use the regular expression pattern, `(.+?)(?:\r\n|\n)(.+[.!?]+[\s|$])` to replace `\n` with .

Issues:

1. A sentence that starts on the same line after another sentence ends does not match.
2. How do I match sentences that have line breaks across more than one line? In other words, how do I allow multiple occurences of `(?:\r\n|\n)`?

   ```
   text = """
   Random Data, Company
   2015

   This is a sentence that has line 
   break in the middle of it due to extracting from a PDF.

   How do I support
   3 line sentence 
   breaks please?

   HEADER HERE

   The first sentence will 
   match. However, this line will not match
   for some reason 
   that I cannot figure out.

   Portfolio: 
   http://DoNotMatchMeBecauseIHaveAPeriodInMe.com 

   Full Name 
   San Francisco, CA  
   94000

   1500 testing a number as the first word in
   a broken sentence.

   Match sentences with capital letters on the next line like 
   Wi-Fi.

   This line has 
   trailing spaces after exclamation mark!       
   """
   import re
   new_text = re.sub(pattern=r'(.+?)(?:\r\n|\n)(.+[.!?]+[\s|$])', repl='\g<1>\g<2>', string=text, flags=re.MULTILINE)
   print(new_text)

   expected_result = """
   Random Data, Company
   2015

   This is a sentence that has line break in the middle of it due to extracting from a PDF.

   How do I support 3 line sentence breaks please?

   HEADER HERE

   The first sentence will match. However, this line will not match for some reason that I cannot figure out.

   Portfolio: 
   http://DoNotMatchMeBecauseIHaveAPeriodInMe.com 

   Full Name 
   San Francisco, CA  
   94000

   1500 testing a number as the first word in a broken sentence.

   Match sentences with capital letters on the next line like Wi-Fi.

   This line has trailing spaces after exclamation mark!       
   """
   ```

[Demo at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/wA2rO6/1/)

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do sentence splitting with a (single) RegEx. There are tools for this, eg. `nltk.tokenize.PunktSentenceTokenizer`, which allows you to do (unsupervised) training in order to learn what abbreviations there are (these are the hardest part in sentence splitting for languages like English). I assume that the sentence splitter won't care about newlines or other whitespace, whereever they be in the sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regex does not match lines that have a space at the end, which was the case with the sentence that was split into 3 lines. As a result, the sentence was not combined into one.

Here's an alternate regex which joins all lines between two empty lines into one, ensuring that there's just one space between the joined lines:

```
# The new regex
(\S)[ \t]*(?:\r\n|\n)[ \t]*(\S)
# The replacement string: \1 \2
```

**Explanation** This searches for any non space character `\S` followed by a new line, then followed by spaces and then by a `\S` again. It replaces the newline and spaces between the two '\S's with a single space. Space and Tab are given explicitly since `\s` matches new lines as well. Here's the [demo link](https://regex101.com/r/wA2rO6/2).